# QPixmap::loadFromData() does not accept JPG data received from TCP/IP

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, jpeg

Since a few days I try to send JPG data via TCP to a QT interface. All images are generated by another process, which makes some GPU-based image processing. The network topology is shown in the below:

[image]
***EDIT***

**Transmitter-side**

Previously, data were processed by an algorithm to BMP24 images. Afterwards BMP images are compressed/encoded to JPGs, in order to reduce the network traffic. Encoding is done by using [this library](https://github.com/CESNET/GPUJPEG) which is used in the following function.

```
void CudaBase::encodeBmpToJpeg(unsigned char* idata, uint8_t* odata, int* p_jpeg_size, int width, int height)
{
    ... // init stuff
    gpujpeg_encoder_input_set_image(&encoder_input, idata); // pass idata which contains interleaved BMP24 data
    gpujpeg_encoder_encode(encoder, &param, &param_image, &encoder_input, &image, p_jpeg_size);  // encode BMP24 to JPG, variable image holds compressed JPG data
    gpujpeg_image_save_to_file(image_dir, image, *p_jpeg_size);  // save JPG on harddrive
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaStreamSynchronize(stream));
    // Copy JPG from image to odata 
    odata = (uint8_t*) malloc(*p_jpeg_size);
    if(odata != nullptr)
        memcpy((void*)odata, (void*)image, *p_jpeg_size);
    else
        printf("Could not allocated memory for jpeg image\n");
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaStreamDestroy(stream));
    gpujpeg_image_destroy(image);
    gpujpeg_encoder_destroy(encoder);
}
```

Now `odata` contains JPG data and is ready to send via TCP, which is done by the following:

```
socket.make_tcp_header(&header, nof_recieved_records, nof_records, ch);
socket.send(&header, sizeof(header));
socket.waitForACK();
socket.send(images[ch], algthm.getImageSize()); // images[ch] points to odata
socket.waitForACK();
```

This is how the transmitter sends

```
template <typename T>
void Socket::send(T* ptr, int count)
{
    printf("Writing to server... \n");
    int result = 0;
    int _size = count;
    do
    {
        result = write(sockfd, (void*)ptr, _size);
        if(result == -1)
        {
            printf("Error sending to server: %d\n",errno);
            _size = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            _size -= result;
        }
    }
    while(_size > 0);
}
```

**Receiver-side**

On the QT client side, JPG data are written to a `QByteArray` and then displayed in a `QLabel` using the `QPixmap::loadFromData()` function, but  `loadFromData()` always returns zero. So it seems that the content of `QByteArray` is not JPG compliant.
When data are received by the client, QT emits a signal and the following readyRead() function is called:

```
void ThreadSocket::readyRead()
{
    static qint64 sum = 0;
    while(socket->bytesAvailable())
    {
        sum += socket->bytesAvailable();
        data->append(socket->readAll());
    }
    // Receive header from client
    if(sum == header_size)
    {
        sum = 0;
        setHeader(stream);
        send("OK");
        emit received_data(META);
    }
    // receive image data
    else if(sum == header.img_size)
    {
        sum = 0;
        send("OK");
        emit received_data(RAW);
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
    clearBuffer();
}
```

***EDIT* ends here**

The following function is a SLOT which is emitted when new (raw) data are received by the client thread.

```
void Controller::refresh_image()
{
    tcp_header *header = socket->getHeader(); // Get header informations from threaded socket
    QPixmap pix;
    switch(header->format) 
    {
        case BMP24:
        {
            QImage img(socket->getData(),
                header->img_width,
                header->img_height,
                QImage::Format_RGB888);
            pix = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
            break;
        }
        case JPEG:
        {
            if(!(pix.loadFromData(socket->getData(), "JPG"))) // Every time return zero
                qDebug() << "Not able to load pixmap from data";
            break;
        }
    }
    // Reload images in GUI
    view->label_list()->at(header->current_channel)->setPixmap(pix);
    view->update();
}
```

Note `tcp_header` is a structure that I have set by myself and is part of my own TCP protocol. Depending on the header, either BMP or JPG images are displayed. Displaying BMP images works without any problems.

After debugging I noticed the following:

1. JPG data sent by the transmitter are exactly the same as those received. In addition, metadata and BMPs are also received correctly.
2. When the receiver loads JPG images from the hard disk with `QPixmap::load(path_to.jpg)`images are correctly displayed in the GUI. (Note the JPGs were generated by the transmitter a few milliseconds before loading).
3. Received data are completely different from those load from the hard disk, whether both have the same source.
4. The size of the transferred bytes is exactly the same as on the hard disk. The data is of type uint8_t at the receiver and at the transmitter.

What could be the reason that the transferred data is different from the data loaded from the hard disk?

Does QT possibly make a conversion internally?

Comment: Note: there are *many* variants of JPEG.

Comment: The QT [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagereader.html#supportedImageFormats) does not state out which JPG formats are supported. It just says JPG and JPEG is supported. Furthermore, reading JPG files on the hard disk works fine, although the content is exactly the same as the data sent by TCP.

Comment: *"Received data are completely different from those load from the hard disk, whether both have the same source."* - you don't show any code how the data are actually sent and received although this is where I would expect the problem to be if the received data are different from the expected ones.

Comment: @One3Three7 provide a [mRe]

Comment: The obvious thing to try is, save that data as .jpg file and try to open it with some other application (as well as with Qt).

Comment: @hyde Exactly this is what I tried. As I tried to explain before, when I read the saved .jpg files with QPixmap::load(path_to.jpg), they are displayed correctly. Only when sending jpg data over TCP, QT does not accept them.

Comment: I mean, receive the data over TCP/IP, *then* save it (instead or in addition to trying to load it to QImage).

Comment: I solved the problem now. The mistake was on the Transmitter side. The pointer array had an incorrect reference and did not point to the jpg buffers. So it was no QT or TCP based problems. Nevertheless, thank you @hyde your approach helped me to figure the problem out!